# Snapcraft: autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required

Tags: snap

I followed the [snapcraft.io/create](http://snapcraft.io/create/) tutorial to create the following `snapcraft.yaml`:

```
name: vokoscreen-snap
version: "2.5.0"
summary: Vokoscreen Screencast
description: Screencast software
  This is part of the snapcraft tour at https://snapcraft.io/create/
confinement: strict

apps:
  vokoscreen:
    command: vokoscreen-snap

parts:
  vokoscreen:
    plugin: autotools
    source: http://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen-2.5.0.tar.gz
```

Running `snapcraft`, however, results in the following error:

```
orschiro@x230:~/Downloads/vokoscreen-snap$ snapcraft 
Skipping pull vokoscreen (already ran)
Preparing to build vokoscreen 
Building vokoscreen 
autoreconf -i
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
Command '['/bin/sh', '/tmp/tmpsmpubw0c', 'autoreconf', '-i']' returned
non-zero exit status 1
```

I made sure that `build-essential` is installed properly. How can I resolve the build error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `autotools` plugin, which is specified in your `snapcraft.yaml` is needed for the `./configure && make && sudo make install` kind of software. (You can check the output of `snapcraft help autotools` to get an idea what it does, what its features are and what it expects.)

Looking at the contents of `vokoscreen-2.5.0.tar.gz`, it likely won't need the `autotools` plugin to build:

```
daniel@daydream:/tmp$ tar xfvz vokoscreen-2.5.0.tar.gz 
./vokoscreen.run
daniel@daydream:/tmp$ file vokoscreen.run 
vokoscreen.run: POSIX shell script executable (binary data)
daniel@daydream:/tmp$
```

The tarball contains only one executable, which looks like it's self-extracting. As far as I know there's no plugin for snapcraft which takes care of that yet, so you might want to write your own plugin. It should be just a [couple of lines of python](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/plugins/).

*Update:* Looking at https://codeload.github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen/tar.gz/2.5.0 you could also just build it from source using the `qmake` plugin.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to proceed with [this snapcraft.yaml](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/489710764173788d07c00b5a84ddaafe) up to the point that it now says `no handler to manage source`. What does that mean concretely?

Comment: Either use https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen/archive/2.5.0.tar.gz as `source` or set `source-type` to `tar`. From the URL snapcraft can't decide what to do. :-)

Comment: Getting closer step by step. :-) Now I just need to find out which package is missing for resolve this error `sh: 1: lrelease-qt5: not found
Project ERROR: alsa development package not found`.

Comment: `libasound2-dev` for alsa I think.

Comment: Solved the problem! The only remaining problem is that you have to manually replace all instances of `lrelease-qt5` with `lrelease` in `parts/vokoscreen/src/vokoscreen.pro` because there is no `lrelease-qt5` command on Ubuntu. Can this be automatised by Snapcraft?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Maybe using a custom plugin? I've seen something like this [over here](https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/blob/master/ubuntukylin-icon-theme/parts/plugins/copy_and_edit.py).

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's best to continue the discussion here [1]. :-)

[1] https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/issues/148